# How to restore multiple SQL Server databases that use the same naming scheme for their MDF and LDF files

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I've got a segment of C# code that restores a SQL Server database. This works well. The issue is running it again on another `.bak` file. Even though the second backup has a different name, it needs to write to the same directory as the first backup and also has the same naming scheme for the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files.

I'm just curious if there is a way to modify the naming scheme of the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files, or if there is some other method to create subdirs under the initial SQL Server directory for these files to be restored to.

Error message that I'm currently getting:

> Additional information: The file XXXXXX.MDF cannot be overwritten. It is being used by database XAXAXAXAX

I figure I could use a move statement, but I am trying to keep from needing all of the directory values hardcoded or logged in a config somewhere.

```
string sql = "SELECT database_id FROM sys.databases WHERE Name = '"+yuy+"'";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"" + singleconn.Replace(@"\\", @"\"));
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
con.Open();

object resultObj = command.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();

if (resultObj == null)
{
    string sql2 = "Restore Database " + yuy + " FROM DISK = '" + @"\" + localdir.Replace(@"\\", @"\") + @"\" + FileName + "'";

    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, con);
    con.Open();
    command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();

    File.Delete(@"\" + localdir.Replace(@"\\", @"\") + @"\" + FileName);
    MessageBox.Show("Database recovered successfully!");
}
else
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int card = rnd.Next(52);
    MessageBox.Show("There is already a database under this name; renaming the DB to " + yuy + card.ToString());

    string sql2 = "Restore Database " + yuy + card.ToString() + " FROM DISK = '" + @"\" + localdir.Replace(@"\\", @"\") + @"\" + FileName + "'";

    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, con);
    con.Open();
    command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();

    File.Delete(@"\" + localdir.Replace(@"\\", @"\") + @"\" + FileName);
    MessageBox.Show("Database Recovered Successfully!");
}
```

Figured most of this out thanks to scsimon, for now the last thing I am getting in terms of errors is this.

Additional information: Logical file 'XXXXXX.mdf' is not part of database 'Databasename'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.

The thing is I am pulling this straight from the Databasename properties.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm just curious if there is a way to modify the naming scheme of the
>   .mdf and .ldf files, or if there is some other method to create
>   subdirs under the initial SQL Server directory for these files to be
>   restored to.

You can use the [`MOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause as you suggested with the `RESTORE` command to *rename* and/or *move* your data files. It looks like this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE myDatabase FROM DISK = '\\somedir\someSubDir\mybackup.bak'
WITH
MOVE 'datafile1' TO 'E:\somedir\new_datafile2.mdf',
MOVE 'logfile'   TO 'E\somedir\new_log.ldf'
```

This was created to move the files from the default location in the backup to another directory (which you can do) but it can also be done to rename them too. Naturally you'd do it for all your `.ndf` too.

> I am trying to keep from needing all of the directory values hardcoded
>   or logged in a config somewhere.

No worries there, just [restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) the database with the [`HEADERONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/view-the-contents-of-a-backup-tape-or-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) to view the contents of the backup like name, date, and other useful info. For the file paths specifically, you'd use [`FILELISTONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). This would prevent you from hard coding them. More on that [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/109/sql-server-restore-filelistonly/).

```
CREATE TABLE #DataFiles (LogicalName nvarchar(128)
                        ,PhysicalName nvarchar(260)
                        ,[Type] char(1)
                        ,FileGroupName nvarchar(128) null
                        ,Size numeric(20,0)
                        ,MaxSize numeric(20,0)
                        ,FileID bigint
                        ,CreateLSN numeric(25,0)
                        ,DropLSN numeric(25,0)
                        ,UniqueID uniqueidentifier
                        ,ReadOnlyLSN numeric(25,0) null
                        ,ReadWriteLSN numeric(25,0) null
                        ,BackupSizeInBytes bigint
                        ,SourceBlockSize int
                        ,FileGroupID int
                        ,LogGroupGUID uniqueidentifier null
                        ,DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0) null
                        ,DifferentialBaseGUID uniqueidentifier null
                        ,IsReadOnly bit
                        ,IsPresent bit
                        ,TDEThumbprint varbinary(32) null
                        ,SnapshotURL nvarchar(360) null
                        )
INSERT INTO #DataFiles
EXEC('RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = ''E:\DB Backups\YourBackup.bak''')

SELECT LogicalName, PhysicalName FROM #DataFiles

DROP TABLE #DataFiles
```

Comment: Ill implement this tomorrow and let you know if this works. thank you for the answer scsimon

Comment: You bet @DigitPlays let me know if you run into issues

Comment: ok, thank you for the help. This would work however I would have to specify both file paths and the mdf/ldf file names. is there a way to change it without specifying that? @scsimon

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You don't have to change the file path--you could keep it the same (as what you get from the FILELISTONLY) and only change the mdf and ldf names to _2 or whatever you want.

Comment: But how do I determine what the file path is before sql unpacks the .bak

Comment: You'd restore with FILELISTONLY. This doesn't actually restore the database, it just reads some information from the backup header and file headers. It should be lightning fast. Once you grab the paths from this result set, you'd use them in the actual RESTORE command where you rename them. Does that make sense?

Comment: That does make a ton of sense. Sorry for additional troubles, let me spend a while implementing this and see what I come up with.

Comment: Ah no troubles at all mate!

Comment: scsimon, If I could ask how do i return the file list info from c#? would I just query the dbname?

Comment: @DigitPlays see the edit. This will give you the logical and physical file names of the files that you can consume however you want. You could wrap this in a procedure and call it with a parameter for the backup name, or just keep it static in a query you pass to SQL Server. You can also just return the PhysicalName if you want, which is the file name.

Comment: Thank you again for all of your help scsimon, one last quick thing I am hoping you can help with. Now that I have successfully retreived all of that info I am getting an error. I will post it as an update in the original question.

Comment: I would also include changing the logical name of the MDF and LDF to match the physical name: `ALTER DATABASE newDB MODIFY FILE  ( NAME = oldDB, NEWNAME = newDB)
GO
ALTER DATABASE newDB MODIFY FILE  ( NAME = oldDB_log, NEWNAME = newDB_log)
GO`

Comment: Ah yes DigitPlays you need to use the logical file name when referencing it in sql server... i.e. when using it in TSQL commands. @HardCode showed how you can modify these file names another way. [Here is a post on that too](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4407/rename-logical-database-file-name-for-a-sql-server-database/)

Comment: Everything is now working. I can not thank you all enough. I offer up my first born as a sign of gratitude. Thank you very much to scsimon and HardCode. pointing me in the right direction you guys are my frickin heroes.

Comment: Just pay it forward brother. Good luck! Happy new year!